# Is my proof of $x^n-y^n = \ldots$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, induction

I am solving problems from Spivak's calculus book's 1st chapter.  Basically Spivak wants me to prove this:

$$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + \ldots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$$

**Question 1:** Is my proof correct?

**Question 2:** How to make it perfect?  Any advise?

---

**My proof:**

I guess Spivak wants to say:
$$
x^n-y^n = (x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
$$

Let:
$$
f(x,y,n) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
$$

Then we can say (is this sub-proof perfect?):
$$\begin{split}
x^{n+1}-y^{n+1} &= (x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n+1} x^{(n+1)-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
                &= (x-y)\left(
                        \begin{split}
                            &x^{(n+1)-(n+1)} y^{(n+1)-1}\\
                            &+ \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{(n+1)-i}y^{i-1}
                        \end{split}
                    \right)\\
                &= (x-y)\left(
                        x^{0} y^{n}
                        + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{(n+1)-i}y^{i-1}
                    \right)\\
                &= (x-y)\left(
                        y^{n}
                        + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{(n+1)-i}y^{i-1}
                    \right)\\
                &= (x-y)\left(
                        y^{n}
                        + x\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}
                    \right)\\
                &= (x-y)\left(
                        y^{n}
                        + xf(x,y,n)
                    \right)\\
\end{split}$$

We can also rewrite what Spivak wants into:
$$
x^n-y^n = (x-y)\Big(y^{n-1} + xf(x,y,n-1)\Big)
$$

We've already proven in [spivak_calc_probs.1.1.2]:
$$\begin{split}
x^2-y^2 &= (x-y)(x+y)\\
        &= (x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=2} x^{2-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
        &= (x-y)\Big(y^{2-1} + xf(x,y,2-1)\Big)\\
\end{split}$$

Then, by induction, we prove that:
$$\begin{split}
x^2-y^2 &= (x-y)\Big(y^{2-1} + xf(x,y,2-1)\Big)\\
x^3-y^3 &= (x-y)\Big(y^{3-1} + xf(x,y,3-1)\Big)\\
\vdots\\
x^n-y^n &= (x-y)\Big(y^{n-1} + xf(x,y,n-1)\Big)\\
\end{split}$$

And since $(x-y)(y^{n-1} + xf(x,y,n-1))$ is only a rewrite of what Spivak
wants, i.e. $(x-y)(x^{n-1}$ $+$ $x^{n-2}y$ $+$ $\ldots$ $+$ $xy^{n-2})$,
therefore Q.E.D already.

---

**alternative proof:**

Using the distributive axiom:
$$\begin{split}
& (x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -y\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -y\left(x^{n-n}y^{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -y\left(x^{0}y^{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -y\left(y^{n-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)\\
&= x\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= x\left(x^{n-1}y^{1-1} + \sum_{i=2}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= x\left(x^{n-1}y^{0} + \sum_{i=2}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= x\left(x^{n-1} + \sum_{i=2}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= \left(x^{n} + \sum_{i=2}^{i=n} x^{n-i+1}y^{i-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= \left(x^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-(i+1)+1}y^{(i+1)-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= \left(x^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i-1+1}y^{i+1-1}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= \left(x^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)
   -\left(y^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= x^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}
   - y^{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\\
\end{split}$$

Then using additive associative axiom:
$$\begin{split}
& x^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}
   - y^{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\\
&= x^{n}
   - y^{n}
   + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}
   - \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} x^{n-i}y^{i}\right)\\
&= x^{n}
   - y^{n}
   + \left(0\right)\\
&= x^{n}
   - y^{n}
\end{split}$$

Comment: How do you justify your very first line of the proof, that $x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=(x-y)(\cdots)$? Try writing $xx^n-yy^n=xx^n-xy^n+xy^n-yy^n$.

Comment: Induction is the hard way.  Simply use distributivity.

Comment: @Chrystomath I just replaced $n$ by $n+1$.  Is this not enough?  E.g. $n$ could be any number, and $n+1$ is just another number.  No?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yeah will do that.  Didn't know.  But for now, is my induction approach perfect?  I am trying to learn how to prove things properly.

Comment: As the alternative is so simple, I dismised from consideration a long and needlessly complex proof.

Comment: @WilliamElliot added my attempt for the simpler proof.

Comment: If a question is supposed to be about your particular - as opposed to asking for any solution - you should include the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. See [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by induction (although in this case it's not the simplest approach, as pointed out in comments) would proceed as follows:

1) Base case - show the the expansion is correct for $n=1$. In this case the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}$ has only one term which is $x^0y^0=1$ so this is straightforward.

2) Assume the expansion is correct for a specifc value of $n$, say $n=k$.

3) Find an expression that relates the $n=k+1$ case to the $n=k$ case. You could try:

$\quad x^{k+1}-y^{k+1} = x(x^k-y^k) + (x-y)y^k$

4) Use (2) to expand your expression from (3):

$\quad x^{k+1}-y^{k+1} = x(x-y)\sum_{i=1}^{i=k} x^{k-i}y^{i-1} + (x-y)y^k\\ \quad=(x-y)\left( x\sum_{i=1}^{i=k} x^{k-i}y^{i-1} + y^k\right) \\\quad =(x-y)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i=k+1} x^{k+1-i}y^{i-1}\right)$

So now you have shown that *if* the expansion is true for $n=k$ then it is also true for $n=k+1$. Together with your base case $n=1$, this proves by induction that the expansion is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Any reason a base case of $1$ is preferred? E.g. $2$ as I used is inadequate somehow?  Also should I add extra text to prove for $n<0$?

Comment: @caveman You can use 2 as a base case if you like, but then you are only proving for $n\ge2$. For $n<0$, the theorem as stated does not make sense because the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x^{n-i}y^{i-1}$ assumes $n \ge 1$. So first you would have to replace the right hand side of the equation by an expression that makes sense for $n<0$, and then you would have to construct a new proof.

Answer (score 1):

More simply, in your first proof, for brevity let $S(n)$ be the sentence $(x-y)f(x,y,n)=x^n-y^n.$ Then, using your calculation that $f(x,y,n+1)=y^n+xf(x,y,n),$ we have $$S(n)\implies (x-y)f(x,y,n+1)=$$ $$=(x-y)(y^n+xf(x,y,n))=$$ $$=xy^n-y^{n+1}+(x)(( x-y)f(x,y,n))=$$ $$=xy^n-y^{n+1}+(x)(x^n-y^n)=$$ $$=x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}.$$ That is, we have $$S(n)\implies S(n+1).$$ And  $S(1)$ is  true because $f(x,y,1)=1.$ So by induction on $n$ we have $S(n)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

Comment: I am a bit confusedby the 1st line.  You said "the sentence $(x-y)f(x,y,n)=x^n-y^n$".  But is this true?  So far I think I proved that $(x-y)(y^{n-1}+xf(x,y,n))=x^n-y^n$.  I don't get  how did you remove the $y^{n-1}$ term and the $x$ scaler.

Comment: The 1st sentence says nothing about the truth of S(n). I am just defining an abbreviation

Comment: I get $S(n)$, but I don't get why did you say that $f(x,y,n) = y^{n-1} +xf(x,y,n-1)$.

Comment: In the 5 displayed lines of your "sub-proof", erase "$x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=$" and erase the term "$(x-y)$" from the RHS of each of the 5 lines and you have a proof that $f(x,y,n+1)=y^n+xf(x,y,n).$

Answer (score 0):

$(a - 1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + ... + 1) =$
$a^n + a^{n-1} + ... + a - (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + ... + 1) =$
$a^n - 1$

Set a = x/y and multiply by y$^n$.